# "prioritize" jobs on assignment problem using Linear Programming in Python

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Is it possible to add a constraint to LP so that it can prioritize the jobs on assignment problem?

The output is Worker-1 will be assigned to Job-1, Worker-2 will be assigned to job-3, Worker-3 will be assigned to Job-2, and Worker-4 will assign with job-4.

Let says, I want prioritize worker-n assigned to Job-2, and Job-3 first, then Job-1, and Job-4

https://machinelearninggeek.com/solving-assignment-problem-using-linear-programming-in-python/

[image]

```
from pulp import *

workers=[1,2,3,4]
jobs=[1,2,3,4]

# Cost Matrix
costs=[[1,2,1,9],
      [4,5,2,2],
      [7,3,9,3],
      [2,3,5,1]]

prob = LpProblem("Assignment Problem", LpMinimize) 
# The cost data is made into a dictionary
costs= makeDict([workers, jobs], costs, 0)

# Creates a list of tuples containing all the possible assignments
assign = [(w, j) for w in workers for j in jobs]

# A dictionary called 'Vars' is created to contain the referenced variables
vars = LpVariable.dicts("Assign", (workers, jobs), 0, None, LpBinary)
# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += (
    lpSum([vars[w][j] * costs[w][j] for (w, j) in assign]),
    "Sum_of_Assignment_Costs",
)
# There are row constraints. Each job can be assigned to only one employee.
for j in jobs:
    prob+= lpSum(vars[w][j] for w in workers) == 1

# There are column constraints. Each employee can be assigned to only one job.
for w in workers:
    prob+= lpSum(vars[w][j] for j in jobs) == 1
# The problem is solved using PuLP's choice of Solver
prob.solve()

# Print the variables optimized value
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
    
# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
print("Value of Objective Function = ", value(prob.objective))
```

output:

```
Output:
Assign_1_1 = 1.0
Assign_1_2 = 0.0
Assign_1_3 = 0.0
Assign_1_4 = 0.0
Assign_2_1 = 0.0
Assign_2_2 = 0.0
Assign_2_3 = 1.0
Assign_2_4 = 0.0
Assign_3_1 = 0.0
Assign_3_2 = 1.0
Assign_3_3 = 0.0
Assign_3_4 = 0.0
Assign_4_1 = 0.0
Assign_4_2 = 0.0
Assign_4_3 = 0.0
Assign_4_4 = 1.0
Value of Objective Function =  7.0
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean by prioritizing. In this model, all jobs are assigned (the number of workers = number of jobs).

Comment: Sorry, should not be on assignment problem. It is scheduling problem.